# Sbt Project Compilation Error java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: O_TMPFILE

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have cloned sbt project and it has compiled successfully and resolved all dependencies.

But when I run it or run a clean test, it gives the following compilation error:

```
[error] java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: O_TMPFILE

[error]     at org.jruby.RubyFile.createFileClass(RubyFile.java:202)
[error]     at org.jruby.Ruby.initCore(Ruby.java:1486)
[error]     at org.jruby.Ruby.bootstrap(Ruby.java:1270)
[error]     at org.jruby.Ruby.init(Ruby.java:1170)
[error]     at org.jruby.Ruby.newInstance(Ruby.java:334)
[error]     at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaEmbedUtils.initialize(JavaEmbedUtils.java:79)
[error]     at org.asciidoctor.internal.JRubyAsciidoctor.createJRubyAsciidoctorInstance(JRubyAsciidoctor.java:126)
[error]     at org.asciidoctor.internal.JRubyAsciidoctor.create(JRubyAsciidoctor.java:57)
[error]     at org.asciidoctor.Asciidoctor$Factory.create(Asciidoctor.java:668)
[error]     at StreamApiBuild$.documentationGenerate(StreamApiBuild.scala:32)
[error]     at $bb5b1f84bcb741e43d80$.$anonfun$StreamService$7(build.sbt:43)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3.$anonfun$apply$2(System.scala:46)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:67)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:269)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:278)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:269)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (Compile / managedResources) java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: O_TMPFILE
```

There is no such file in our project O_TMPFILE.

But when i comment the following lines in my build.sbt, it works fine.

```
.settings(resourceGenerators in Compile += task[Seq[File]] {
      documentationGenerate((resourceManaged in Compile).value, name.value, version.value, baseDirectory.value)
    })
```

I need to understand the cause of the error and permanent fix. I have googled more than enough but it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `documentationGenerate` uses jRuby internally, and jRuby has problem with java 11 (not sure if case here). My proposition is to run sbt using java8 and see what happens.

https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/5334

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I am aready using java8. I checked there were some java 11 libraries but i excluded them. But it gave same result.